# Get all String fields' values

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class like this

```
Class Constants {
    public static final String A = "abc";
    public static final String B = "xyz";
}
```

I want to get the values of all these String fields and add them to an arrayList

```
List<String> myStrings = new ArrayList<>();

Field[] fields = Constants.class.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field : fields) {
    myStrings.add(field.getName());
}
```

Now `field.getName()` gives the name of the field, i.e. `'A'`, but what I want is it's value `'abc'`.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (Field field : fields) {
    myStrings.add(field.getName());
    myStrings.add((String)field.get(Constants.class));
}
```